# Using dynamic arrays vs SQL

Tags: sql, database

I've been asked that and remained speechless.

Suppose you have two options for implementing the backend of some application.

One is using a dynamic array and each time you want to modify/read it, you load it to RAM and do whatever you want, and then store it back when finished.

The other, is using SQL.

Other than the performance issues (SQL is faster, if the DB is bigger than the RAM you can't load it to the memory), are there any other reasons for preferring  SQL?

Comment: When you say vector do you man an in-memory list?

Comment: @JimmyT. I mean like vector in java or any other data structure you prefer.

Comment: A vector is a data structure and SQL is a language used for querying relational DBs. This question in its current form makes no sense.

Comment: @mickfold So? you can implement the same functionality using both.

Comment: It's like asking: "which is better - Python, or arrays?"

Comment: @Hogan I can store whichever data type I want in vector

Comment: @Hogan SQL is is used to query tables. I can store the same records in a vector and call it a table and then I can query it using "regular" java.

Comment: If you are talking about this:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html Then you really mean "dynamic array".  As it says in the first line.

Comment: @Hogan You're right, I'll edit the question

Comment: Oh, this is a Java question?! Perhaps you should tag it as such, and refer to `java.util.Vector` rather than just "vector"

Answer (score 3):

Transactions...

Scalability

Concurrency

SANITY!

Whoever proposed using Vectors for an application, give them some building blocks and put them in a room with no sharp corners...

Comment: Why is concurrency an advantage?

Comment: @Shmoopy Do you even understand the topic?

Answer (score 0):

If it is about storing more data a database is the better choice in most cases.

Databases have a better performance because they are optimized for these operations:

- ACID
- Loading only some of the data
- ...

Comment: Yes but as I stated in the question you extract the vector from non-volatile memory and store it back when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Like most design issues the answer depends on context.  How big is this data, how often is it used, what platform are you running on, etc etc etc.

For example, the .NET platform essentially uses an array (with some additional features I know) to store configuration information.  At the start of the program this information is loaded from disk and then whenever you need to check a configuration parameter it looks into the array to find it.

There are additional features like cache control etc -- but lets ignore them for now.

This structure makes sense.  The information is read once at the start of the program, it is not modified by the program and it does not need to be written back to the storage medium.

So the answer to your question really depends on what you are doing with the data. As Martin pointed out SQL provides a number of important features to applications besides those you mentioned including transaction control, concurrency, structure and scaling.